# how to use auto layout in portrait and landscape for different iphone screen sizes

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I am using auto layout in storyboard to arrange multiple controls.But controls like button with image and image views are not fitting correctly in landscape mode.
Thanks

Comment: After introduction of Size Classes there is no orientation like term in iOS 

Use Size classes

Comment: Can you suggest me good tutorial for size classes @techloverr

Comment: Please check answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35884251/2963912

Answer (score 0):

After introduction of Size Classes there is no orientation like term in iOS Use Size classes

Please refer

https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/size-classes-ios8-xcode-6

http://www.hossamghareeb.com/size-classes-tutorial/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwSTXY0awng